# Onclick function not working for glyphycons in reactjs component

Tags: reactjs

I have a react component for table, the table heads are sortable. I notice the texts in that th are working well for onclick method but the glyphicons are not working for onclick method although both are in same anchor. The code is as follows:

```
columns.push(
  <th key={index} data-nw-id={column.id} className={className.join(' ')}>
    {column.canSort
        ?
            <a href="#" className="u-textLink" onClick={e => {
                e.preventDefault();
                if (e.target.className == 'u-textLink' && allowSort) {
                    this.sortByColumn(e, column);
                };
            }}>
                {content} {this.props.sort == column.id
                    ? <span className={'icon-chevron-' + (this.props.order == 'asc' ? 'up' : 'down')}></span>
                    : null
                }
            </a>
        : content
    }

  </th>
);
```

Comment: I would recommend to place both of them in a container div and place the onClick on the container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the onClick method also in the following tag. For e.g:

```
{content} {this.props.sort == column.id
            ? <span onClick={e => this.sortByColumn(e, column)} className={'icon-chevron-' + (this.props.order == 'asc' ? 'up' : 'down')}></span>
            : null                                
          }
```